# Enable Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring with Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to enable [Kubernetes Engine Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/) on clusters but I don't see that as a field in Terraform's [`google_container_cluster` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html).

Is Kubernetes Engine Monitoring managed with another resource?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the newer Kubernetes Monitoring Service by setting [`monitoring_service`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_cluster.html#monitoring_service) to `monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes` instead of the default `monitoring.googleapis.com`.

When enabling this you will also need to set `logging_service` to `logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes` as well.

Comment: ah ha! so thats the same as checking off that little "Enable Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring" checkbox when creating a new cluster via the GUI?

Comment: Yes, but you need to actually put two settings together `monitoring_service = "monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes"` and `logging_service = "logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes"`. Just setting the `monitoring_service` will throw and error when performing `terraform plan`